# Remove tag and content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to get the content of a specific `#id`, remove a few tags and its contents, add some html before and after it, and then set that finished content as the body content.

I now have the following code, containing a mixture of Javascript and jQuery, although obviously not the right one - resulting in a `[object Object]`-message.

My code looks like this:

```
var printContents = jQuery("#"+id).clone();
var printContentsBefore = '<html><head></head><body><table><tr>';
var printContentsAfter = '</tr></table></body></html>';
var mainContents = printContents.find(".td_print").remove();

document.body.innerHTML = printContentsBefore + mainContents + printContentsAfter;
```

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Comment: mainContents is a jQuery object. You'll need to set mainContents to printContents.html();

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want your code to do. For one, you're setting the `body` to something resembling a full html string. Please include a more complete repro of your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not convert the cloned jquery object to a string. Modify your code as follows:

```
document.body.innerHTML = printContentsBefore + mainContents.html() + printContentsAfter;
```

Beware that the `.html` method output will not include the html representation of the container element itself (ie. of the `#id` clone in your case).